# Installing scapy3 on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, python-3.5, scapy

Pretty new to both scapy and python so apologies for what may be a thickheaded question.

I know that it is new and may have issues on Windows but I have successfully installed scapy3 on Windows 2012r2 and Ubuntu Linux. Unfortunately, I actually hope to use it on Windows 7 and am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\Scripts\\scapy", line 25, in <module>
    interact()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scapy\main.py", line 293, in interact
    scapy_builtins = __import__("scapy.all",globals(),locals(),".").__dict__
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .arch import *
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from .windows import *
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    ifaces.load_from_powershell()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 151, in load_from_powers
hell
    for i in get_windows_if_list():
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 86, in get_windows_if_list
    name, value = [ j.strip() for j in i.split(':') ]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I have searched via google and on stackoverflow but have not found a solution.
Any guidance appreciated.

platform is Windows 7 and python35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer: you are using a fork of scapy that does not officially supports windows 7.

Since very recently, the original secdev/scapy fork supports Python 3, so there is need to keep using the one not supporting windows 7 :-)

Feel free to have a look at
**https://github.com/secdev/scapy**